# How do I rip off an enemy's arm in Stubbs the Zombie?

Tags: stubbs-the-zombie

In the game Stubbs the Zombie, how do I rip off people's arms? I can't seem to figure out how to do this consistently, it only happens sometimes when you repeatedly use the melee attack...is there a button combo I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to melee the enemy enough to stun them (but most enemies will then just die).

From what I observed, this triggers only for strong enemies (like the chainsaw guys), or soldiers with a helmet, since you can't eat their brain.

The button is then the same as for eating brain.

Answer (score 2):

I've only played the demo but the instructions are:

> Approach the enemy and press the Y button to tear his arm off

Answer (score 0):

First you have to trigger an unholy fart by clicking F and press E to rip his/hers arm off. Happy Slaughtering!